# Reduce time needed to succesfully establish a connection between a BLE server and a BLE client

Tags: esp32

I've an ESP32 board that acts as BLE server and connect to a BLE client running on another ESP32 board.
I've noted that putting in deep sleep mode the first ESP 32 board (*what that is running as BLE server*) at least 3 secs are needed to succesfully connect to the BLE client.

Obviously every time the BLE server goes in deep sleep, the BLE connection is lost and every time it is waked up at least 3 secs are needed to reconnect to the BLE client.

The question is:
is there any way to reduce the time needed to succesfully establish the connection BLE server -> BLE client every time the BLE server is waked up ?
Any idea.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Look into “bonding”, a type of BLE device “pairing” that establishes a permanent connection.

Comment: @MarkU
Hi MarkU
Very interesting. I'll search on internet on how to do this. Thanks